# Batch compare 2 directories and output names of folders from 2nd directory

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, echo

I would like to compare the existence of subfolders with a same name in 2 different directories. Sometimes the same names may be spelled lowercase in the source and uppercase in the target directory. I would like to output the name of the subfolder from the target directory.

```bat
@echo off

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b "%SystemDrive%\Folder1"') do (

    IF exist "%SystemDrive%\Folder2\%%~a" (

    echo %%a

    )
)

exit
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%a IN ("%SystemDrive%\Folder1\*"') do (
    for %%b in ("%SystemDrive%\Folder2\%%~nxa") do echo %%~nxb
    )
)
```

If the file doesn't exist in `folder2`, the `for %%b` simply doesn't compute, so you don't need `if exist`.

Comment: What I want is to have the name of the subfolder as it is in the target directory if it exists in the source. For example, if in the Folder1 folder there is a "test" subfolder (in lowercase) and in the Folder2 folder there is a subfolder with the same name but in uppercase like "TEST", I would like it to get the name of this subfolder (in uppercase).

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Does that work better?

Comment: It doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell this can be accomplished several ways, one being like so:

```powershell
$dir1 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\dir1 -name
$dir2 = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\dir2 -Name
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $dir1 -DifferenceObject $dir2 -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual
$compare | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

Changing the path to each directory is all you would need in this case. It should return just the names of the folders in both locations.

Sorry to intervene, I know this isn't PowerShell...Just stumbled across this and would like to assist.

Please delete if not allowed.

Comment: Your answer needs to be changed a little to reflect the question asked. Currently you're outputting all of the child item names, the question is only about the directories, and should technically use the same paths, for example, `$dir1 = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Env:SystemDrive\Folder1" -Directory -Name`, and `$dir2 = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Env:SystemDrive\Folder2" -Directory -Name`.

Comment: Good catch, didn't read it thoroughly. Good thing there's a `-Directory` parameter. Guess we can also add a `-Recurse` as well if needed. Also, looks like he found the answer!

Comment: They haven't found an answer, because in what they've posted, the first `for /f` loop does not isolate directories only either! Also, PowerShell version 3.0+ is required for the `-Directory` option, and the original question and code does not make it clear that a recursive operation is wanted.

Comment: Hence the "if needed".  I'd honestly be surprised if there's anyone  still running v1, or v2. Most users are on at least 5.1, but  there are a few who have their reasons on why they're not. Welp, seems like theyd rather stick to batch files so I won't put in my extra 2 cents lol. Anyways, have a good rest of your Sunday!

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it :

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('"dir /b %SystemDrive%\Folder1\*"') do (
    for %%b in ("%SystemDrive%\Folder2\%%~a") do echo %%~nxb
    )
)
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: This does not answer the question you asked!